# Плашки для ответов

Tags: поддержка, ответы

На сайте о Русском языке наткнулся на [такой ответ](//rus.stackexchange.com/a/31425):

[image: скриншот]

Обращаю внимание на плашку под ответом:

> Информация из этого сообщения нуждается в дополнительных ссылках. Пожалуйста, добавьте в сообщение подтверждающие цитаты из надёжных источников. Материал без указания ссылок может быть оспорен или даже удалён.

Как это сделано и есть ли у нас возможность использовать эту функциональность?

Answer (score 3):

Эти плашки доступны модераторам:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответственно, самый простой способ ей воспользоваться: связаться с модератором в чате или через тревогу "требуется вмешательство модератора
".

Comment: Только эти 3 варианта? Чего-нибудь кастомного туда не упихивается?

Comment: @Qwertiy мне о возможности расширения списка не известно.

Comment: Жаль.. В таком случае он не слишком полезный :(